# Kafka: Have each poll() call only consume from one topic at a time?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a single Kafka consumer that consumes from multiple kafka topics. I'd like to be able to use a batch write into my destination via 1 i/o call per 100 messages, but in order to batch, all the messages need to come from the same topic.

If I have multiple topics (let's say 5), and when consumer.poll or consumer.consume happens, and I get for example 100 messages each poll, is there a way to ensure that those are all from the same topic, so that those messages can be batch written to the same destination? Such that the next .poll call gets the next topic?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this?

Comment: trying to be lazy without having to spawn a consumer for each topic (we have hundreds of topics but some of them don't get messages for days, while others get a couple per second), but at the same time be performant because the message destination database responds better to batch writes based on topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to poll per topic - you are subscribed to a list of topics and each topics may have multiple partitions. A given poll fetches a `ConsumerRecords` object, which is a container of `ConsumerRecord`. A `ConsumerRecord` represents a KV pair which belongs to one of the partitions of one of the topics which you have subscribed.

Kafka tries to assign a `TopicPartition` to consumers forming a single group based on an assignor. If you have only one consumer, it will claim all of the partitions of all of the topics. Then there is nothing that stops you from grouping within your application code though

e.g.

```
private void consume() {
    List<String> topics = List.of("topic1", "topic2", "topic3", "topic4", "topic5");
    kafkaConsumer.subscribe(topics);

    while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = kafkaConsumer.poll(1000);

        topics.forEach(s -> {
            List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> recordsPerTopicPartition = new ArrayList<>();
            consumerRecords.records(s).forEach(recordsPerTopicPartition::add);
            doWhatever(recordsPerTopicPartition);
        });
    }
}

private void doWhatever(List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> consumerRecords) {
    //process
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to handle topics is the following: each `ProducerRecord` has a method `topic()` which returns topic name for that record. You then can group by topic and do whatever you want with pairs of topic and collection of records for this topic.

But I strongly suggest to use separate KafkaConsumer for each separate topic if you want to handle topics independently.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to subscribe to multiple topics while polling messages topic per topic is to use the pause/resume methods.

Here is a example :

```
        List<String> subscription = List.of("topic-a", "topic-b");
        consumer.subscribe(suubscription);

        final Map<String, List<TopicPartition>> partitionsPerTopic = 
                consumer.assignment()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TopicPartition::topic, Collectors.toList()));

        int next = 0;
        consumer.pause(consumer.assignment());
        // Starting consumption
        while (!closed.get()) {
            // Resuming consumption for next topic
            final String topic = subscription.get(next);
            consumer.resume(partitionsPerTopic.get(topic));

            consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(500)).forEach( records -> {
            ...
            });   

            // Pausing consumption for current topic
            consumer.pause(partitionsPerTopic.get(topic));
            next = (next + 1) % subscription.size();
       }
```

However, this solution could be not efficient because consumer can still has buffered messages for the previous fetchable partitions. Those messages will be drained and fetch again on second iteration.

In other terms, that solution can increase network roundtrip between the consumer and the brokers.